# Should I build the relationships with the database schema or deal with them programmatically?

Tags: sql, database

Should I build the relationships with the database schema or deal with them programmatically?

For Example When I build the database in MSSQL I can to not build the relationships and deal with the relationships programmatically like checking if a key is exist as a primary key in another table and determine upon that to insert the new row to the table or not.

could anyone advise me if it is a good practice or not.

Comment: When you're talking about foreign key constraints, yes, that's advisable when you want to force referential integrity not only on application layer.

Comment: Keep in mind that it is quite common that data outlives an application that provides user interface to manipulate this data. Also, it is quite common that the same database is used by several different applications. So, it is a good idea to enforce referential integrity at the database level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**DO** make relationships between tables explicit by declaring foreign key constraints.

I do not see any good reason for not doing this. Why are foreign key constraints a good idea?

- Foreign key constraints are a simple way to help safeguard data integrity/consistency.
- Constraints (not just foreign key ones) can also be seen as a form of "living documentation" (making things explicit and therefore discoverable, without having to guess).
- You might still want to validate inserts in code; in that case you can look at foreign key constraints as a "safety net", in case your code fails.

(Regarding the second bullet point above: I have to work with one legacy database which is lacking some foreign key constraints that should by all means have been declared. This means that every time I have to make a change to it, I might inadvertently break an application that makes certain assumptions about the schema that aren't obvious by looking at the schema. Working with this database is very painful and error-prone. If I could change one thing about this database, it would be to add all missing constraints.)

Answer (score 0):

it depends upon your need.
If you are designing OLTP applciation then builing relationship is good but if you designing datawarehouse DWH or datamart then it is advisable not to establish relationship in schema and handle it in code.